# ExpressJS send data to jade (now called pug) on when calling render method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I've created few REST APIs using ExpressJS. DB that I'm using is oracle.

What I want to do it pass results from one of the API calls to `render` method.
For example:

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey'});
});
```

In this `res.render('index',` ... I'd like to pass data from REST call here so I can use it in my jade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supplied very little code, but perhaps you want something like this (assuming you've already created a connection pool named connPool):

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  connPool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    conn.execute('select * from emp', function(err, result) {
      res.render('index', result.rows);
    });
  });
});
```

I've not added any error handling, this is just to convey the idea...

Comment: Can you actually create pools on verion 10XE?
I've figured I could do something like that but what I've wondered is : is it actually practical/modular?

Comment: I honestly don't know how much code to provide :/ If you have anything in mind I'm willing to provide it. I wrote a small wrapper (using node driver ) for execution of sql. I export that and use it in my REST route. I'm kinda wondering if I could use that REST route and send the results of it to my render function.

Comment: Yes, you can use connection pools with 10g XE. You should consider moving to 11g XE.

Start with what you know you can do and go from there. Make it better, more modular.

You should be able to use your wrapper with your REST routes... Exactly how that would work would depend on your wrapper.

Comment: Thank you , I'm aware now that I tried to bite off more than I can chew :) I'm using my wrapper in my REST route , and I export that route as a module.

Comment: I do wish I could upgrade but unfortunately it's not up to me.